# Problems with single anonymous access aspx in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, anonymous

I got a SharePoint Project which already works with anonymous Access. Now I added an aspx-page which is used for streaming images. That aspx-page is added into a virtual directory
Layouts\

Whenever I try to access that aspx-file Sharepoint does not allow anonymous access to that page even though all other pages viewable by the user work fine with anonymous access. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Which behaviour you mean? Your behaviour? I hope that there is a way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two requirements must be met:

1. the page needs to inherit from the class [UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.unsecuredlayoutspagebase.aspx),
2. the property [AllowAnonymousAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.unsecuredlayoutspagebase.allowanonymousaccess.aspx) needs to be overridden to return `true`.